# In Place SQL Upgrade and SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, upgrade, ssis-2017, ssis-2014

I am planning an in-place upgrade of a SQL server 2014 to 2017. We have many SSIS packages deployed to the server. Anybody know if the upgrade will convert the deployed packaged to 2017 format or will I have to re-deploy them all?

I know that if I do redeploy of any packages I would have to change the target version in the solution, I'm just wondering if the upgrade will require me to re-deploy them all or will it do the conversion on the currently deployed packages on the SQL server side.

Comment: If you have any questions regarding an upgrade, test the heck out of it on a development server.

Comment: I do have a test server. I'm just trying to plan the scope of this project before starting it. The scope will be much different if I have to re-target all the packages and redeploy them as well. I've googled it but cannot seem to find any information on if you need to do anything with already deployed packages with an in-place upgrade.